# scope of javascript callback functions

Tags: javascript, function, callback, scope

I was wondering what is the scope of a passed in callback function in Javascript.

```
callback = function() {
    alert('hello');
}

func1 = function() {
    func2(callback);
}

func2 = function(callback) {
    func3(callback);
}

func3 = function(callback) {
    callback();
}
```

When I call func1() .. it seems as if this extra layer of function loses that reference to callback(). I can call callback() from within func2, but not func3. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: How are you calling those functions?

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/QZL6M/

Comment: What is your expected output, and what is the actual output? Perhaps the question should include those explicitly, then ask, why is my mental model of reality different than the browser's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should see your code written as

```
var callback;
var func1;
var func2;
var func3;

callback = function() {
    alert('hello');
}

func1 = function() {
    func2(callback);
}

func2 = function(callback) {
    func3(callback);
}

func3 = function(callback) {
    callback();
}
```

the func1 scope includes all variables callback, func2 and func3. since all functions are initialized using function expressions and not function declarations like

> function callback() {alert('hello');}

calling func1 will alert hello only if it is called at the bottom of your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I have explained some of this in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubergoober/QZL6M/5/). Look over the comments in the JS. This was done in a hurry, so feel free to update/comment/question. Code is below if you'd like to put test it locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>

      <div id="test">
      </div>

      <script>


        // We're going to name our /callback/ something else to help with
        // the confusion of using /callback/ wording everywhere.
        var showMessage = function(message) {
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= message;
        }

        var tellMe = function(message) {
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = message;
          return "Oh yes we did!";
        }

        // here we'll have one called callback just to show the name callback isn't anything special
        var callback = function(message) {
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= message;
        }

        // doesn't show anything, because you're not passing in a call back.
        // if we wanted this to work we would have a param called callbackTest and
        // we's pass in a function to be called back.
        func1 = function() {
          func2(callbackTest("Hi from func1"));
        }

        // does show message because you're not calling a callback, you're calling a function directly. Which is what you were doing above, just that there happened to not be a function called callback
        // see explination below why we don't see Hi from func2, but Hi from func1_5 instead
        func1_5 = function() {
          func2(callback("Hi from func1_5"));
        }

        // here we're actually accepting a callback function named showMessage and using that as our callback by assigning it to the callback parameter variable. (remember, callback is not a fancy statement or call or anything. It's just a commonly named variable for.... callbacks ;) )
        func2 = function(callback) {
          // what you're doing here is actually passing the result of calling the callback (showMessage) to func3, and not the function. So you're actually executing the callback (showMessage) with the "Hi from func2", which outputs that, but returns nothing. So you're not passing anything at all to func3.
          func3(callback("Hi from func2"));
        }

        // so here we'll show the previous problem, but working to provide insight.
        // we're passing in a different /callback/ called tellMe. This function actually returns a string.
        func2_5 = function(callback) {
          func3(callback("Hi from func2_5"));
        }

        // here you're actually passing in a function to this as a callback, which is actually the showMessage function we pass in below.
        func3 = function(callback) {
          // the thing is, the callback variable is now a string and not a function because we got the result of the passed in callback call from above.
          // so this will show a string for callback ("Oh yes we did!")
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = callback;
          // and this won't show anything because callback is not a function in this scope
          if (typeof(callback) !== "function") {
            alert("callback isn't a function");
          }else {
            callback(("Hi from func3"));
          }
        }

        func4 = function() {
          if (typeof(callback) === "undefined" ) {
            alert ("the callback variable was never defined")
          } else {
            callback(("Hi from func4"));
          }
        }



      </script>

      <button onclick="func1();">func1</button>
      <button onclick="func1_5()">func1_5</button>
      <button onclick="func2(showMessage);">func2</button>
      <button onclick="func2_5(tellMe);">func2_5</button>
      <button onclick="func3();">func3</button>
      <button onclick="func4()">func4</button>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded and executes in function-level blocks. How is there a race condition here?

Comment: I guess race condition isn't the right term here. I removed the alert and had it updating an element, so the content was getting over written too fast to see what was happening. Either way I put buttons so each func could be run individually. I was in a hurry when I wrote it. I'll update to remove the race condition comment.

Comment: @JoeFrambach .. I'm also used to working with node, so dealing with callbacks and race conditions with async tasks gets me paranoid when I don't get back what I expect. :)